# Enlace en el botón de inicio

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Tengo una web en WordPress. Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que un usuario que esta logado, si pulsa en el icono de la pagina (Situado en la cabecera de la web), le lleve a la pagina que yo le diga, y no a la home, ya que en esta seria donde inicia sesión, y yo lo que quiero es que le lleve a una pagina donde tengo información general. Me comentarón con JavaScript mediante Cookies. Espero haberme explicado, desde ya Muchas gracias.

Comment: No se si he entendido bien, pero quieres que al pulsar un botón te lleve a una pagina que tú elijas? Al pulsar dicho botón con un `href` bastaría para enviarlo a la pagina que tu quieras.

Comment: El tema es que el usuario estará logado, si no esta logado le lleva a la home que es donde esta la ventana de inicio de sesión. Una vez iniciada la sesión y si pulsa en el logo es cuando le llevaría a otra pagina que denominare como info.

Comment: Hola @ManuelHernandezGordo, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Podrías utilizar la variable $_SESSION de php para saber si el usuario se logueó y así redireccionarlo a la pagina que desees.

Comment: Perfecto, pero eso no quita de que si pincha en el icono de logo de la web, le lleve a la home como te comentaba.

Answer (score -1):

espero estes teniendo un buen día.

Puedes comprobar si un usuario ha hecho login, mediante esta función de Wordpress: [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/), te permitirá conocer si está activa, de ser así, ajustas el enlace a tus requerimientos.

Prueba una sentencia como está:

```
<?php 
$home_url = get_site_url();

if(is_user_logged_in()){
    $home_url = ''; //My custom url here
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola Raylin, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Aunque puede servir de ayuda para resolver el problema expuesto, sería ideal que añadieras algo más de información (como una descripción/explicación de lo que hace el código, o enlaces con referencia). Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.